# binning and plotting in R/python

Tags: r, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I have following data set:

```
1   yes 50  60  35  40  44
1   No  10  2   40  
2   yes 50  60  35  40
2   No  10  2   40  8   6
3   yes 50  60  35  40  35
3   No  10  2   40
```

There are several bins like 1,2,3... which has values for two categories ( Yes and No). Number of values in each category might not be the same. I am trying to get a plot which looks something like below. I have used only simple plots like heat maps or scatter plots but never done this sort of plot before. can anybody help with this ? **I am happy to reformat the data structure.**

[image]

Comment: One option would be `library(dplyr);library(tidyr); library(ggplot2); gather(df1, Var, Val, V1:V5) %>% filter(!is.na(Val)) %>% ggplot(., aes(x=factor(Bin), y=Val, fill=factor(Categ)))+geom_dotplot(binaxis='y',stackdir='center', position='dodge') +xlab('Bin') +ylab('value')`

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to reformat your data as a dictionary of dictionaries, so that the first-level keys were your 1,2,3 and your second level were your yes/no values. I then plotted the data using the data numbers as y coords and bin values as x coords, for which the x-values were increased by 0.5 for No values. Please see the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

a = [1,'yes', 50,  60, 35, 40, 44]
b = [1,'No' , 10,  2 , 40 ] 
c = [2,'yes', 50,  60, 35, 40]
d = [2,'No' , 10,  2 , 40, 8,  6]
e = [3,'yes', 50,  60, 35, 40, 35]
f = [3,'No' , 10,  2 , 40]

dic = {}

for data in [a,b,c,d,e,f]:
    reference = data[0]
    if reference in dic.keys():
        data.pop(0)
    else:
        dic[data.pop(0)] = {}
    dic[reference][data.pop(0)] = data

plt.close('all')

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(3.35,3.35))

#Plot data numerically to achieve plot
for a_bin in dic.keys():
    #So that the No values appear shifted on the x-axis
    ax.plot([a_bin+0.5]*len(dic[a_bin]['No']) ,
             dic[a_bin]['No'] ,'rx')
    ax.plot([a_bin]*len(dic[a_bin]['yes']),
             dic[a_bin]['yes'],'bo')

#So all data fits nicely onto plot
ax.set_xlim((ax.get_xlim()[0]-0.5,ax.get_xlim()[1]+0.5))
ax.set_ylim(0,70)

#Reformat the tick labels, so plotted according to yes/no
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['']+['yes','No']*len(dic.keys())+[''])

fig.show()
```

[image: Produced Image]

Hope this is what you're looking for!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when I run the code above, I could see nothing happens on my terminal. No output, No warnings and no errors. I am using Python 2.7.10.

Comment: Did you put fig.show() (plt.show() also works) onto the end? It's just hanging off the end of the scroll bar.

Comment: No problems, glad it helped!